# How to make an interface function when it won't always be the same?

Tags: java, function, methods, interface, package

I have to make an interface for a package. This interface needs `calculateVolume()` and `calculateSurfaceArea()` methods. The problem is that this interface will be used by `Cube`, `Sphere`, and `Cylinder` classes, which have different formulas for solving these. So I am wondering how to make the interface functions so that all three different calculations are satisfied?

Side question: How do I make a `clone()` method and what is that used for?

Comment: In Interface you can declare only the method signature, Actual implementation will be in the implementing class. Different implementing class can have different logic

Comment: So in the interface I wouldn't actually do any of the calculations? Just put " calculateSurfaceArea(){}"?

Comment: @pleasehelp: *"So in the interface I wouldn't actually do any of the calculations?"* Right. I suggest stepping back from your current task and working through some basic Java tutorials.

Comment: No, just `calculateSurfaceArea();` (without the `{}`, and you'll also need a result type such as `double` or whatever). An interface can _never_ have an implementation.

Comment: It should be like   public int calculateSurfaceArea();

Comment: +1 to @T.J.Crowder. SO is best for asking specific, focused questions, not for replacing a basic tutorial. Using it as a tutorial will get you downvotes, but more importantly you're likely to miss important concepts that you didn't even know to ask. There are lots of programming and Java tutorials out there; online courses like `coursera` with TAs and grading; etc. You can learn this stuff the right way, for free.

Comment: You are entirely missing the point of interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your interface, you declare the methods, but you don't implement them.  That's what an interface is: a list of methods with parameters and return types that do different things, but without any of the implementation.  For example:

```
public interface Shape
{
  double calculateVolume();

  double calculateSurfaceArea();
}
```

And then, when you come to implement the interface:

```
public class Cube
  implements Shape
{
  private double sideLength;

  @Override
  public double calculateVolume()
  {
    return sideLength * sideLength * sideLength;
  }

  // etc.
}
```

[The Oracle tutorials on interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) should make all this clear.

Answer (score 1):

Same name, different implementation, isn't it what interfaces is for? Clone is for making full copy of object (copy of all members).